# C# cache layer issues, locks & DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching

I have the Cache layer described below. The problem is that I need to get Lists or specific element from List, and then modify it, then persist it to db, and update the cache list.
So to avoid problems between the cache layer & DB layer, when getting data from cache I should make/get a copy of it, so it doesn't get changed down the way (if it's changes DB layer throws an error).
Question is how to properly approach this copy strategy, and other question is should the lock be present for add/remove operations too? (if yes, what is the right way to lock prior to modify?)

The cache is a singleton DI through services.

```
services.AddSingleton<MyCache>();

public class MyCache
{
    private readonly AsyncLock _mutex = new AsyncLock();
    public MemoryCache Cache { get; set; }

    public MyCache()
    {
        Cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());

        // populate cache from DB
    }

    public async Task<List<UDT>> GetUDTsForUser(string id, bool fetchFromDB = false)
    {
        List<UDT> list = new List<UDT>();
        Cache.TryGetValue(id, out list);
        if (list == null)
        {
            using (await _mutex.LockAsync())
            {
                Cache.TryGetValue(id, out list);
                if (list == null && fetchFromDB)
                {
                    var DAO = new DAO();
                    list = (await DAO.GetInfoForUser(id))?.UDTs;
                    if (list != null)
                    {
                        Cache.Set(id, list);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    public async Task<UDT> GetUDTForUser(string id, long udtId)
    {
        List<UDT> list = new List<UDT>();
        Cache.TryGetValue(id, out list);
        if (list == null)
        {
            using (await _mutex.LockAsync())
            {
                Cache.TryGetValue(id, out list);
                if (list == null)
                {
                    var DAO = new DAO();
                    list = (await DAO.GetInfoForUser(id)).UDTs;
                    Cache.Set(id, list);

                    return list.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == udtId);
                }
            }
        }

        return list.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == udtId);
    }

    public void AddElement(UDT udt)
    {
        if (udt == null)
            return;
        
        var udtList = Cache.GetOrCreate(udt.GroupId, entry => {
            return new List<UDT>();
        });
        if (udtList.Contains(udt) == false)
        {
            udtList.Add(udt);
            Cache.Set(udt.GroupId, udtList);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveElement(string groupId, long udtId)
    {
        var udtList = Cache.Get<List<UDT>>(groupId);
        if (udtList != null)
        {
            udtList.RemoveAll(e => e.Id == udtId);
            Cache.Set(groupId, udtList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to research optimistic concurrency. However, you are likely reinventing the wheel here, though its hard to tell with out a more descript use case

Comment: @TheGeneral Well, basically, I have N opened websockets. Every websocket receive one of 2 type of messages (in 2 words - add/delete). When I receive a message I either update the set in my DB (cassandra) by adding or removing an element, then adding or removing this element from cache too. But sometimes it can be that while updating DB using list/object from Cache - it gets changed and so in the DB is an inconsistency (as well maybe as in Cache).

Comment: This is what they call a write-through cache, there are many solutions which would guarantee they are never stale. It depends if this is write heavy or not. The simplest solution would be to synchronize access, update the cache then the database then release the lock, also you could use optimistic concurrency (though i am not sure Casandra has this) . However, if this is for production i would consider just using something off the shelf like redis, or may others